# How is Cassandra column-oriented and at the same time suitable for OLTP?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have read in the Concise guide to database book that a Column-oriented database is not the right vehicle when it comes to OLTP, it is good for aggregation because it accesses directly the column without the need access to each row first. That's why I get confused when I heard that Cassandra is suitable for OLTP more than OLAP.

I tried to search alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Cassandra is not a column-oriented database.  It is a partitioned row store.  It stores data in the following structural hierarchy:

column values -> rows -> partitions -> tables -> keyspaces.

Cassandra is capable of scaling to handle high levels of operational (OLTP) throughput because it uses a distributed hash to place data in the cluster.  Rows correspond to hashed values of their partition keys, and the driver properly routes key-based operations based on that.

So no, it is not at all column-oriented.

Comment: I am sorry but it may be a stupid question --> If Cassandra is a partitioned row store,  Why is RDBMS not partitioning in the same way Cassandra does? This will help us to use it in heavy OLTP and distribute the data

Comment: @AlyAyman No worries.  RDBMSs generally are restricted to a single machine and don't need to worry about finding the best network path to all of its data replicas. 
 Cassandra was designed to be distributed across multiple machines from the beginning, so its design had to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

Tables in Cassandra used to be called "column families", meaning that tables contain groups (families) of columns. Let me illustrate with an example.

Consider this list of users:

| ID | Username | Firstname | Lastname | Email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | alice12 | Alice | <null> | alice12@mail.com |
| 2 | b0b | Bob | Vasquez | fixer@builder.co |
| 3 | ch5r71e | Charli | Yang | <null> |

Traditional databases would store this data in rows:

```
1,alice12,Alice,<null>,alice12@mail.com;
2,b0b,Bob,Vasquez,fixer@builder.com;
3,ch5r71e,Charli,Yang,<null>;
```

Column-oriented databases (aka columnar DBs) would store the same list by column:

```
1,2,3;
alice12,b0b,ch5r71e;
Alice,Bob,Charli;
<null>,Vasquez,Yang;
alice12@mail.com,fixer@builder.co,<null>;
```

Cassandra would store the data in rows of the columns name/value pairs:

```
"users" : {
    row1 : { "ID":1, "Username":"alice12", "Firstname":"Alice", "Email":"alice12@mail.com" },
    row2 : { "ID":2, "Username":"b0b", "Firstname":"Bob", "Lastname":"Vasquez", "Email":"fixer@builder.co" },
    row3 : { "ID":3, "Username":"ch5r71e", "Firstname":"Charli", "Lastname":"Yang"}
}
```

As you can see from the example, Cassandra stores the data into rows of columns which is the reason Cassandra tables are referred to as column families.

It should be obvious by now that "column families" is completely different from "column-oriented". It is unfortunate that these two phrases commonly get confused with one another.

Cassandra is *not* a column-oriented database. Cheers!

Comment: What about Hbase ? It is the same because it is said that is column oriented and the same time suitable for OLTP